# c# need to have one extension method for various classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, extension-methods

What i am trying to do is i need to have one extension method for all my models.

Let's assume i have 3 class/models.

- Model 1
- Model 2
- Model 3

i am trying to do something like this in my extension method (was not able to succeed).

```
public static IQueryable<T> IncludeAllInfo<T>(this IQueryable<T> model)
    {
        if(model.getType().ToString() == "Model1")
        {
           var newModel = model.asQueryable<Model1>();

           return newModel.Include(a => a.Model2).Include(a => a.Model3);
        }
        elseif(model.getType().ToString() == "Model2")
        {
           var newModel = model.asQueryable<Model2>();

           return newModel.Include(a => a.Model3);
        }
    }
```

is this possible or must i create overload method for each type?

Comment: Use a method for each model and you can get rid of the if statements and the casts

Comment: Instead of IQueryable use DbSet

Comment: Why is an extension method required? Can this not be implemented on the classes directly?

Comment: @mohsen Can you explain why? I could not see any reason for that

Comment: @the.Doc At which classes? The IQueryable<Model1> class?

Comment: If you're using generics and you end up doing a bunch of if statements to determine the type you're basically showing that the code is not generic.  Instead you should use overloads for each type.

Comment: @juharr alright i guess that's it. more code but maintainable.

Comment: @SirRufo yea ignore. Misread the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create 1 method per type.

```
public static IQueryable<Model1> IncludeAllInfo(this IQueryable<Model1> model) { 
  return model.Include(a => a.Model2).Include(a => a.Model3);
}

public static IQueryable<Model2> IncludeAllInfo(this IQueryable<Model2> model) {
  return model.Include(a => a.Model3);
}
```

This is easier to test, maintain, read, and it is less code than what you have above.

Comment: the reason i was asking is that i am trying also to implement another method which allows selective includes for all models. for example, i want to include only this for this model and so on. but i guess it's just the same as what you suggested, code length wise i guess it won't matter since what matters is maintainability and testability.

Answer (score 2):

Create one extension for every entity

```
    public static IQueryable<MyEntity> IncludeAllInfo(this Dbset<MyEntity> model)
    {

           return model.Include(a => a.Model3);

    }
```

Or

```
    public static IQueryable<MyEntity> IncludeAllInfo(this IQueryable<MyEntity> model)
    {

           return model.Include(a => a.Model3);

    }
```

Comment: Why should anyone use DbSet<> instead of IQueryable<>?